# How should I reformat my data for sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB

Tags: python, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I have a dataset `users`. Each user has gender and color property (favorite color), and so on. I divided each color and sum of users of one gender which like this color to one list:

```
features_train = [['indigo', 2341], ['yellow', 856], ['lavender', 690], ['yellowgreen', 1208], ['indigo', 565], ['yellow', 103], ['lavender', 571], ['yellowgreen', 234] ...]
```

In the second list for each element from the first list I say which gender represent this element:

```
labels_train = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...]
```

And now I have the third list with colors: `features_test = ['yellow', 'red', ...]`, and I need to predict a gender.

I have to use `naive_bayes.GaussianNB` function from `sklearn` and I will have more properties for `users`, but to explain my problem I use just color and gender. So, I found an official example but I can't understand how should I reformat my datasets to work with them. Should I convert my color to some number representation like: `[[0, 2341], [1, 856]]` or maybe I should use some another function from `sklearn` to do that?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)
print(clf.predict(features_test))
```

Comment: Convert the colours to integers, and try running your code.

Comment: I did not understand. Do you want to use the second element of each list (the feature about "sum of users of one gender")? If yes, then you need to supply it also when predicting the data. Anyways, scikit-learn estimators dont support strings in X. You need to convert them to numerical as suggested by @Shiva .

Comment: [sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) might help you to convert 1D array of strings to numeric values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to perform 'machine learning' on text documents with scikit-learn, you first need to turn the text content into numerical feature vectors.

The most intuitive way to do so is the bags of words representation - you can solve that by indeed reformatting your dataset like you have mentioned.

Given that your 'X' and 'y's are both 1-D I would recommend to convert your text classes into a set of numerical feature vectors by using the LabelEnconder in scikit-learn.

See below:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

clf = GaussianNB()
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()


#Fit label encoder and return encoded features
features_train_num = le.fit_transform(features_train)
features_test_num  = le.transform(features_test)

#Fit label encoder and return encoded labels
labels_train_num   = le.fit_transform(labels_train)
labels_test_num    = le.transform(labels_test)

clf.fit(features_train_num, labels_train_num)
print(clf.predict(features_test_num))
```